# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' message despite having selenium downloaded

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to import selenium in PyCharm community edition 2018.8.2 and it gives me this error:

**This is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
usr = input('Enter your username or email : ')
pwd = getpass("Enter your password : ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
usr_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
usr_box.send_keys(usr)
pwd_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
pwd_box.send_keys(pwd)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.submit.EdgeButton.EdgeButton-- 
    primary.EdgeButtom--medium')
login_button.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed selenium using:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium #for python3
```

Or:

```
sudo pip install selenium #for python2
```